# Session-based login system - warning via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, session

I have a problem with a session-based login (implemented with PHP, HTML and CSS). So far so good. Now I want when you make a wrong input, that a warning appears. First I just created a second page with an additional warning. But it would be better to implement this in AJAX (maybe with jQuery). But now I have a problem. Since I have implemented the AJAX part I can´t login. Everytime the warning appears. When I remove the AJAX request all works. It seems that the php validation part is no longer called. But I don´t know why. Here is the code:

This is a part of the validation (loginscript.php). The login form has the name loginform and the submit.button the name login.

```
else if (isset( $_POST['login'] )) 
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $clean_username = strip_tags(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($username)));

    $clean_password = (strip_tags(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($password))));

    $hash_password = saltedHash($clean_password, $clean_username);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $loginTable WHERE $attUsername = '$clean_username' AND $attPassword = '$hash_password'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) 
    {
        $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
        echo 'correct';
        header('refresh:2;url=ajax/cmapp.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

The shown part doesn´t work since I use that:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#tr1").hide();
/* sendung formular abfangen */
$("#loginform").submit(function() {
                                /* ajax objekt zum aufruf & versand an das skript
    'name' und 'email' sind in der data-zeile die variablen für das php-skript */
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loginscript.php",
        data: "username=" + $("#username").val() + "&password=" + $("#password").val(),
        success: function(msg)
        {
            if (msg == 'correct')
                {
                    alert("hjlkjl")
                    window.location='ajax/cmapp.php';
                }
            else
                {
                    $("#tr1").hide().load("message.html").fadeIn(0);
                }
```

Everytime the else part is executed.

Comment: Downloads? `.txt`? Include the code in your question! If the code is to long then you might need to trim it down. Moreover, your question doesn't contain a question yet.

Comment: consider adding the relevant code in the question body...

Comment: @MRae: we like code in questions here, so that broken links don't affect the usefulness of questions into the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `data` value should include a `login` variable, else the PHP script won't enter the conditional. and since you use POST, you can use an object as the `data` value

```
data : {
  username : $("#username").val(),
  password : $("#password").val(),
  login : true,
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have tried it. But without success. Every time the else branch is executed...

Comment: try debugging then. see what your php script actually returns. `success: function( msg ){ console.log( msg ) ..` and have a look into the javascript console. or change `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` and open the php page with url parameters ( `loginscript.php?login&username=xxx&password=xxx` ) and see, what it shows you.

Comment: Also, get rid of the `header("refresh...` line